# Can't compile microsoft example CppAndPython

Tags: python, c, visual-studio

I have started looking at C++ and Python, I am new to both of these languages and am struggling to understand why the example given by Microsoft doesn't work.

In the code below PyModuleDef is not recognised but i cant figure out why.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>

const double e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527;

double sinh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 - pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double cosh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 + pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

PyObject* tanh_impl(PyObject *, PyObject* o) {
double x = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
double tanh_x = sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
return PyFloat_FromDouble(tanh_x);
}

static PyMethodDef superfastcode_methods[] = {
// The first property is the name exposed to Python, fast_tanh, the second is the C++
// function name that contains the implementation.
{ "fast_tanh", (PyCFunction)tanh_impl, METH_O, nullptr },

// Terminate the array with an object containing nulls.
{ nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }
};

static PyModuleDef superfastcode_module = {
PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
"superfastcode",                        // Module name to use with        Python import statements
"Provides some functions, but faster",  // Module description
0,
superfastcode_methods                   // Structure that defines the            methods of the module
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_superfastcode() {
    return PyModule_Create(&superfastcode_module);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Can the compiler even find `<python.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're compiling against the obsolete Python 2 and its `<Python.h>`. The `typedef` [`PyModuleDef` appeared in Python 3](http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html#module-initialization).

---

The solution is to ensure that you're compiling and linking against Python 3.

Comment: ok thats propbably it thanks, i changed the environment in visual studio to Pythin 3 but didn't change the path where it was picking up the include files...

Comment: @user7168829 also please provide the *error message* in the question

Comment: It simply said “not recognised” in the intellisense.

Comment: @user7168829 then if you try to compile?

Comment: I get this message 
Unable to resolve 'superfastcode'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module. CppAndPython C:\Users\Aspen\Desktop\python-sample-vs-cpp-extension-master\CppAndPython\CppAndPython.py 40

And it fails to run the C code.  But no errors when compiling

Comment: @user7168829 that has no bearing to the previous one

Comment: True, by implication though the other problem has gone away.  Still cant run the downloaded example.

Comment: @user7168829 Ah, that's worth asking another question!